# Class Based FormView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have researched this issue for a couple of days and can't seem to find what I'm looking for exactly.  I have searched ModelChoiceField as well as ChoiceField on StackOverflow as well as Google and there are many variations of my question but nothing exactly.  In a nutshell, I am trying to use a Class Based FormView and then capture the user selection and pass it to a Class Based ListView.  Here is my code.

Forms.Py

```
class BookByStatus(forms.Form):

   dropdown = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[],required=False)

   def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookByStatus, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
        self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
        self.fields['dropdown'].choices = 
        Book.objects.values_list("author","author").distinct("Publisher")
```

The code above works fine, and shows me the output I'm looking for on my view.  No issues there....Then I have my FormView...

```
class BookByStatusView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookByStatus
    template_name = 'xyz123/publisher.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Book:book_by_list',kwargs=
                               {'dropdown':'dropdown'})

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BookByStatusView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user        
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.request.POST['dropdown']
        BookByStatusView = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']
        return super(BookByStatusView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The code above works fine, but takes me to the ListView below which I can't seem to pass the dropdown value to....I've tried several different iterations of get_form_kwargs as well as changed my form to ModelChoiceField, but still can't seem to understand how to get a queryset based on the input from the user...

And finally the ListView...

```
class BookByStatusListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookByStatus
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'xyz123/book_by_status_list.html'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self, *kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        dropdown = self.kwargs.get('dropdown', None)
        if form.is_valid():
            return Book.objects.filter(dropdown__icontains=form.
            cleaned_data['dropdown'])
        return Book.objects.all()
```

I'm trying to take the dropdown input from the FormView and then pass it to a list view using two separate views.  I need to pass the value from the FormView to the ListView.  I'm clear on how to get the data in the FormView in the ChoiceField, and how to display a ListView, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the dropdown data from the FormView to the ListView.  I can get the ListView to work, but only with the full queryset, not with a filtered one.

Here's the book model....

```
class Book(models.Model):
    Author CHOICES = (
        ("New","New"),
        ("Old","Old"),
    )

    Author = models.CharField(choices=Author_CHOICES,max_length=10)
```

Here's the URL...

```
url(r'^book_by_list/(?
P<dropdown>\w+)/$',views.BookByStatusListView.as_view(), 
name='book_by_list'),
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Updated Approach...Using request.session.  My prior approach would not let me pass the value from the one view to the other, no matter how many get_context_data or get_form_kwargs combinations I tried.  Based on the input I received, I began exploring the request.session approach and I've gotten much further.  One last piece remains, getting the request.session value in my LISTVIEW so I can filter my querysets accordingly.

```
class BookByStatusView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):

    model = Book
    form_class = BookByStatus
    template_name = 'xyz123/publisher.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Book:book_by_list') 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.request.session['dropdown'] = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']
        return super(BookByStatusView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BookByStatusView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

And in my html template, I leverage the request.session value as...

```
{{ request.session.dropdown }}
```

And I reverted the URL back to..

```
url(r'^book_by_list/$,views.BookByStatusListView.as_view(), 
name='book_by_list'),
```

The last remaining piece is to figure out how to leverage the LISTVIEW with this approach.

My current Listview:

```
class BookByStatusListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookByStatus
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'xyz123/book_by_status_list.html'
    paginate_by = 15

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Book.objects.none()
    dropdown = self.request.session.get('dropdown')
    if dropdown == 'New':
        queryset = Book.objects.all()
    elif dropdown == 'Old':
        queryset = Book.objects.none()
    return queryset
```

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the dropdown value correctly to the ListView so the queryset is displayed properly.  Based on my testing, I don't appear to be capturing dropdown properly in the get_queryset function.  Any ideas?

I figured it out.  I updated the get_queryset with the proper syntax.  Thanks for all of the help to nudge me in the right direction.  Last questions..is this the best way to pass a value from one view to another?  Is there a better way to do this?  Are there any concerns with this approach?

Comment: Please can you show the Book model, its get_absolute_url1() method, and the URL.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I did some more research last night and from what I can tell I could use a URL to pass the value to the LISTVIEW?  I played with several options but couldn't get that to work either.  Is that generally what I should be trying to do?

Comment: I really can't understand what you are trying to do here. Apart from anything else, your BookByStatusView `form_valid` method cannot possibly work, as you get a string from the dropdown and then try and call `get_absolute_url1()` on it. But you really need to explain exactly *what* you are trying to display on the ListView.

Comment: I am trying to use a dropdown on the FormView to essentially pass a value to the ListView.  I have updated my FormView this am and I'm a step closer..I have updated the formview code to include KWARGS and I have also updated the URL to include the KWARG that I am sending to the LISTVIEW.  This is now working...I am successfully passing the KWARG to the URL, but not the actual value.   I am still trying to figure out how to get the value.  I suspect it's GET_Context_Data or Get_queryset, but haven't figured that out yet...I have updated my code above with the latest updates.

Comment: I've added a new line to the form_valid function in my FormView, and tested that the system is in fact getting the value that the user is selecting, by adding Print(self.request.POST['dropdown']) to the code, but still can't figure out how to send the value as a KWARG to LISTVIEW.  The KWARG is still coming through as DROPDOWN, not the value I'm capturing in the FORMVIEW...

Comment: Should I be using a different type of view for this function?  I am trying to stick with class based views.  I'm open to changing the formview if something else makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, because redirect creates a new request/response and data from previous are lost. If I understand what you want correctly, one of the options would be to save the drop-down value to session in `BookByStatusView` and then retrieve it in `BookByStatusListView`.

You save to session with:

```
request.session['dropdown_value'] = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']
```

and retrieve with:

```
dropdown_value = request.GET.get('dropdown_value')
```

Here is [How to use session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) part of Django documentation.

EDIT: You can also pass the value as an url parameter like this:

```
author = 'michael cricthon'
title = 'kongo'
year = [1999, 2000, 2001]
type = ['electronic', 'print', 'hardcover', 'softcover']

params = '?author={}&title={}&&year={}&type={}'.format(
            urllib.parse.quote_plus(author), 
            urllib.parse.quote_plus(title),
            ','.join(year),
            ','.join(type))

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search') + params)
```

The link would look like this:

```
../search/?author=michael+crichton&title=kongo&year=1999,2000,2001&type=electronic,print,hardcover,softcover
```

You get parameters with

```
author = request.GET.get('author')
title = request.GET.get('title')
... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will research that.  I am using class based views, does that matter based on your input above?  I have also begun exploring passing the value via a URL.  Would that work?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use CBV. You could pass the value via URL if it's a simple value like a number, a string or a list. I'll update the answer with the option of passing value as a URL parameter.

Comment: Request.session has taken me much further with my code.  Last piece is to try to get the value in my listview.  I have updated my solution with what I've tried so far.  All works with the exception of the queryset filtering.  Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Believe I solved it.  Updated the code above to reflect my final answer.  Thanks for the help.